# How to monitor when the body 'data' attribute changes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have data-segment attribute in my body tag that is changed by a slider. I need to trigger a function based on the value of this, when it is changed.

I'm not sure how to attach an event listener in this case though?

Comment: Could you use the event on the slider activating to check the value?

Comment: Does not the slider fire an event when it changes value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`There is no reliable cross-browser way to receive an event when a DOM node attribute is changed. Some browsers support "DOM mutation events", but you shouldn't rely on them, and you may Google that phrase to learn about the ill-fated history of that technology.

If the slider control does not fire a custom event (I would think most modern ones do), then your best bet is to set up a `setInterval()` method to poll the value.

Comment: I'd prefer a `setTimeout()` looping on itself than a `setInterval()`, simply due to the fact the `setInterval()` may get backed up and cause issues, possibly misreporting.

Comment: @Jared - I disagree in this case. The time it takes to check a single node's attribute is negligible. "backups" are pretty unlikely, and setInterval is semantically much nicer. A possible misreporting would be rectified upon the subsequent execution of setInterval. It'd be a different story if we were dealing with a remote service or other high-potential-latency situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MutationObserver`, which is an API [available in every browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) and avoid polling with `setInterval`. If you have a reference to your element in `element`, you could do this:

```js
const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);
mutationObserver.observe(element, { attributes: true });

function callback() {
  // This function will be called every time attributes are
  // changed, including `data-` attributes.
}
```

Other changes in your element can be easily detected with this API, and you can even get the old and new values of the property that changes in your callback tweaking the configuration object in the call to `observe`. All the documentation about this can be read in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit

Answer (score 0):

Since in my use case all of my `.data('type', 'value')` is set inside javascript block anyway, so in my case I just put a `.change()` chain right after the `.data(...)` and access the update using the normal `$("#oh-my-data").change()`

Which works fine for me, see the demo.

```js
$("#oh-my-data").change(function() {
  $("#result").text($("#result").text() + ' ' + $(this).data('value'));
})

$("#oh-my-data").data('value', 'something1').change();

$("#oh-my-data").data('value', 'something2').change();

$("#oh-my-data").data('value', 'something3').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="oh-my-data" type="hidden" data-value="" /> Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

But this solution have a problem, which is that if the `.data()` is set by an external library, then this will not work since you can't add the `.change()` on top of it.